# JPA session with lazy collections in Vertx EventBus consumer

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, vert.x

I have created a consumer on Vert.x eventbus:

```
@Autowired
private Vertx vertx;

public void registerConsumer() {
    EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus();

    eb.consumer("action.request", (Message<String> msg) -> {
        handleIncomingRequest(msg);
    });
}
```

In the `handleIncomingRequest` chain, I call a service to fetch an entity from a psql database:

```
private void handleIncomingRequest(Request request) {
    SystemNode system = systemService
            .getSystemWithHistoryFrom(request.getUuid());

    // All lazily initialized collections unavailable here

    systemService.update(system);
}
```

In the method above, I try to do some operations on collections in the `SystemNode` object. However, the lazily initialized collections on this object are never fetched. I have tried setting `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` and `FetchType.EAGER`. When I inspect the object, I can see that it is a persistent set and it shows me the following error:

> com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.

Further inspection shows that the session related to this persisent set is null, so calling `Hibernate.initialize(system.getSomeCollection())` will throw an exception.

Both of these approaches solve the problem, but this isn't an option because the collection is way too big to fetch each time if it isn't going to be used.

Calling the service anywhere outside the eventbus consumer gives me a collection that can be initialized on demand.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you should wrap your incoming request handling logic into a single transactional method, to prevent entities from getting detached between the calls to `systemService.getSystemWithHistoryFrom()` and `systemService.update()`. Something like `@Transactional public void SystemService.getSystemHistoryDoImportantStuffAndSaveResults()`.

Alternatively, you could customize the query executed by `systemService.getSystemWithHistoryFrom()` to `JOIN FETCH` all the necessary collections and keep the collections lazily fetched within the entity itself. But wrapping the entire business logic within a transaction is much safer as it enforces transaction isolation *in addition to* solving your problem.

Comment: You are right, I moved the logic that should be transactional to a new class and annotated the entry point with `@Transactional` and it seems to be working based on what I've tried so far. Thank you!